# If $G$ is an abelian group, then inverse of $x$ is equal to $x$?

Tags: group-theory, abelian-groups

True/False

If $G$ is an abelian group, then the inverse of $x$ is equal to $x$, true or false and why?

Comment: Pick your favorite abelian group. Pick your favorite element of it. Perform an empirical check.

Comment: It is true for some abelian groups, like the Klein-4 group.  But you should understand, jenn, that you should read a question like this as a universal claim:  "For all abelian groups G,  then for all $x \in G$, $x\in G,  $x^{-1} = x$.  So my recommendation is that you check more than two of your favorite abelian groups, including cyclic and non-cyclic.

Comment: Not sufficient, @Thorgott, to pronounce true or false based on one empirical check.  If Jenn's favorite group was $\mathbb Z_2$, or the Klein-4 group, she might be lured into believing the statement is true.

Comment: What exactly did you try? What do you know? Where is this question from? I am voting to close this question because lack of context.

Comment: Already a group with $3$ elements refutes this claim. Really not too difficult to find a counterexample here.

Comment: Ah, yes. 3 downvotes. That'll show 'em.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Obviously false. Consider $\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}$ with addition. Then

$$1+2 = 0 = 2+1$$

so $2$ is the inverse of $1$, yet $1 \neq 2$.

And there are plenty more counterexamples.

---

Note: the converse to your statement does hold.

That is, if every element in a group is equal to its inverse, then the group is abelian. Indeed, if $G$ is such a group and $g,h \in G$, then

$$gh = g^{-1}h^{-1} = (hg)^{-1} = hg$$

An example of a group where every element is equal to its inverse is $\mathbb{Z}_2 \times \mathbb{Z}_2$, as @amWhy notices in the comments.

Comment: Well said, and I like the observation that the converse of the statement does hold. +1